# Joining 2 df through look up in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I'm having a headache with performing a join on data frames through look up:

`df1`,

```
Name ID1    StartDate1  EndDate1    StartDate2  EndDate2
ab   111    1/1/2017    3/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017
bc   112    2/1/2017    3/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017
cd   113    1/1/2017    2/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017
df   114    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017
fe   115    4/1/2017    5/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017
```

`df2`,

```
ID1 ID2 Date     Id1_num  id2_num
111 10  1/1/2017    10      11
111 10  2/1/2017            10
111 10  3/1/2017    13      13
111 10  4/1/2017    15      13
112 20  2/1/2017    11      19
112 20  3/1/2017    12  
112 20  4/1/2017            19
113 20  1/1/2017    17       5
113 20  2/1/2017    17      14
114 30  2/1/2017    11      13
114 30  3/1/2017    10  
114 30  4/1/2017    18      13
115 30  4/1/2017    7        5
115 30  5/1/2017    13      19
```

I want my result `df3`,

```
Name   ID1    ID2   StartDate1  EndDate1    StartDate2  EndDate2    ID1Date1Count   ID1Date1Average   ID1Date2Count    ID1Date2Average    ID2Date1Count    ID2Date1Average    ID2Date2Count    ID2Date2Average
ab     111    10    1/1/2017    3/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2               11.5              2                14                 3                11.33              3                12
bc     112    20    2/1/2017    3/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2               11.5              2                11.5               1                19                 2                19
cd     113    20    1/1/2017    2/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2               17                1                17                 1                14                 1                14
df     114    30    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    3               13                3                13                 2                13                 2                13
fe     115    30    4/1/2017    5/1/2017    2/1/2017    4/1/2017    1               19                0                0                  1                19                 0                0
```

Where 
`ID1Date1Count` is the entries count from the date interval `[StartDate1, EndDate1]`,
`ID1Date2Count` is the entries count from the date interval `[StartDate2, EndDate2]`
`ID2Date1Count` is the entries count from the date interval `[StartDate1, EndDate1]`
`ID2Date2Count` is the entries count from the date interval `[StartDate2, EndDate2]`
Along with their average.
The extra condition here is that we do not include `num` if `num < 10`.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Which is the link of df1 and df2 ?

Comment: Opps! There should be a ID1 column in df 2 let me edit it.

Comment: I edited it. Hope it make sense now

Comment: the solution for this will be very long ...what have you try ?

Comment: I tried to remove all value that is less than 5 then merge the 2 df.  However, I can't get the count based on the day interval.  It took me a long time already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke down the steps, after we get the `dd1`, we can `merge` it back to your `df1`, you can replace `NaN` by using `fillna(0)`

```
Newdf=pd.wide_to_long(df1,stubnames=['StartDate','EndDate'],i=['Name','ID1'],j='nnumer')
Newdf.StartDate=pd.to_datetime(Newdf.StartDate)
Newdf.EndDate=pd.to_datetime(Newdf.EndDate)
Newdf['New']=Newdf[['StartDate','EndDate']].apply(lambda x : [pd.date_range(x['StartDate'], x['EndDate'],freq='MS').tolist()],1)['StartDate']
Newdf=Newdf.set_index(['StartDate','EndDate'],append=True).New.apply(pd.Series).stack()
Newdf=Newdf.to_frame('Date').reset_index()
df2.Date=pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
dd=Newdf.merge(df2,on=['ID1','Date'])
dd[['Id1_num','id2_num']]=dd[['Id1_num','id2_num']].mask(dd[['Id1_num','id2_num']]<10)
dd1=dd.groupby(['ID1','nnumer','StartDate','EndDate'])['Id1_num','id2_num'].agg(['mean','count']).unstack(1).groupby(level='ID1').ffill().bfill().reset_index(['StartDate','EndDate'],drop=True).drop_duplicates()

dd1
Out[626]: 
       Id1_num                     id2_num                 
          mean       count            mean       count     
nnumer       1     2     1    2          1     2     1    2
ID1                                                        
111       11.5  14.0   2.0  2.0  11.333333  12.0   3.0  3.0
112       11.5  11.5   2.0  2.0  19.000000  19.0   1.0  2.0
113       17.0  17.0   2.0  1.0  14.000000  14.0   1.0  1.0
114       13.0  13.0   3.0  3.0  13.000000  13.0   2.0  2.0
115       13.0   NaN   1.0  0.0  19.000000   NaN   1.0  0.0
```

Updated

```
dd1.columns=dd1.columns.map(''.join)
dd1
Out[650]: 
     Id1_nummean1  Id1_nummean2  Id1_numcount1  Id1_numcount2  id2_nummean1  \
ID1                                                                           
111          11.5          14.0            2.0            2.0     11.333333   
112          11.5          11.5            2.0            2.0     19.000000   
113          17.0          17.0            2.0            1.0     14.000000   
114          13.0          13.0            3.0            3.0     13.000000   
115          13.0           NaN            1.0            0.0     19.000000   
     id2_nummean2  id2_numcount1  id2_numcount2  
ID1                                              
111          12.0            3.0            3.0  
112          19.0            1.0            2.0  
113          14.0            1.0            1.0  
114          13.0            2.0            2.0  
115           NaN            1.0            0.0
```

Comment: Based on your code, how do you know which StartDate and EndDate do we using since there are 2 for each? Thanks for the help

Comment: @TylerNG do you notice the nnumer column I create ? 1 is the startdate1 2 is startdate 2 :-)

Comment: @TylerNG seems like this is not what you need right ?

Comment: Almost but not exactly.  I need it in the format that I mentioned above since I have to run pivot and graph on the data later on.  I was about to do it on excel but I need to implement it in python.   I'm pretty new to python ;[  However, I'm using your code as a guideline to see if I can come up with anything right now. ;]

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I have 2 questions regarding your code?
1.  Can I merge dd1 and df1 together based on ID1?  I tried to do with pd.merge(dd1, df1, how = 'left', on = ['ID1']) but I got an error onID1.
2.  If I have an extra id3_num in my df2 where should I modify the code?  
Btw, You're a great help!

Comment: @TylerNG `pd.merge(dd1, df1, left_index=True,right_on = ['ID1'], how = 'left')`
, you can modify it `dd.groupby(['ID1','nnumer','StartDate','EndDate'])['Id1_num','id2_num','Id3_num'].agg(['mean','count']).unstack(1).groupby(level='ID1').ffill().bfill().reset_index(['StartDate','EndDate'],drop=True).drop_duplicates()` BTW if my answer help, can you consider accpeted it and upvote : -) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on what you actually want (e.g. what is "num < 10", which num? Id1_num or id2_num?), but the below should get you close I believe.

first -- group df2 and format it into the date intervals:

```
df2_grouped = df2.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2']).\
    apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x['Date'].min(), x['Date'].max(), 
                               x['id2_num'].count()],
                              index=['StartDate2', 'EndDate2', 'ID1Date1Count']))
df2_grouped = df2_grouped.reset_index()

print(df2_grouped)

    ID1 ID2 StartDate2  EndDate2    ID1Date1Count
0   111 10  1/1/2017    4/1/2017    3
1   112 20  2/1/2017    4/1/2017    1
2   113 20  1/1/2017    2/1/2017    2
3   114 30  2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2
4   115 30  4/1/2017    5/1/2017    2
```

Then -- merge it with your df1:

```
df1[['ID1', 'StartDate1', 'EndDate1']].merge(df2_grouped, on='ID1')
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['StartDate2'])

print(df1)

    ID1 StartDate1  EndDate1    ID2 StartDate2  EndDate2    ID1Date1Count
0   111 1/1/2017    3/1/2017    10  1/1/2017    4/1/2017    3
2   113 1/1/2017    2/1/2017    20  1/1/2017    2/1/2017    2
1   112 2/1/2017    3/1/2017    20  2/1/2017    4/1/2017    1
3   114 2/1/2017    4/1/2017    30  2/1/2017    4/1/2017    2
4   115 4/1/2017    5/1/2017    30  4/1/2017    5/1/2017    2
```

Again, the output doesn't exactly match your desired output, but its close.

Comment: the num here is if either id1 num or id2 num is less than 10 then I want to ignore that.  The problem here is that I want to use the date range to count. 
For example, 111 for ID1
[1/1/2017, 3/1/2017] has 2 entries with avg is 11.5
[2/1/2017, 4/1/2017] has 3 entries with avg is 11.33